# Customizing inclusion guards in eclipse CDT

Tags: eclipse-cdt, include-guards

Is there a way to customize the format of inclusion guards in eclipse CDT for the class generation template? The current format is `<Class Name>_H`, but what I would like is something like `<namespace>_<namespace>_<class name>_H`. Not that I expect to have classes with the same name in different namespaces within my own project, but I'd prefer not to worry about it should the case arise.

Comment: I recently asked something similiar (no answers yet): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520943/eclipse-cdt-use-namespace-in-automatic-generated-include-guards

Comment: I also asked the same question before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402665/how-to-customize-eclipse-cdt-code-templates There are some answers, but nothing really satisfactory.

Comment: I realize this may not be exactly what you're looking for, but for any compiler that isn't really ancient or really weird, I prefer `#pragma once`.

Comment: The trouble with `#pragma once` is that as it's not a standard part of the language you can't be sure that any compiler (including sexy modern ones) will recognize it. Include guards are still the safest, most portable, solution.

Answer (score 2):

There is hard way to do this. You can rebuild plugin CDT plugin. Information about code repository and needed enviroment for rebuild available [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Getting_started_with_CDT_development). In your case you need change behavior of `generateIncludeGuardSymbol()` method that in

> core/org.eclipse.cdt.ui/src/org/eclipse/cdt/internal/corext/codemanipulation/StubUtility.java

More about it described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9545933/902217) answer

Answer (score 2):

I like Stuart's answer here:

[How to customize eclipse CDT code templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402665/how-to-customize-eclipse-cdt-code-templates)

Just customize the template.

So in the Preferences dialog under C/C++ -> Code Style -> Code Templates you can modify the template to be closer to what you need, for example if you need the namespace in the guard, you can do something like.

```
${filecomment}

#ifndef ${namespace_name}_${include_guard_symbol}
#define ${namespace_name}_${include_guard_symbol}

${includes}

${namespace_begin}

${declarations}

${namespace_end}

#endif /* ${namespace_name}_${include_guard_symbol} */
```

Answer (score 1):

This is in Neon...

Open up `Window/Preferences`.
Go down to `C/C++/Code Style/Name Style`.
Under `Code` you will find `Include Guard`.
It looks like some customization is allowed there.

This is the thing that gets expanded to `${include_guard_symbol}`.

Comment: Does not work for me. There is a radio button which offers 1) Filename path relative... 2) File name 3) Unique identifier. No editable string field. Eclipse Neon 4.6.0.

Comment: Does not work for me either. Has anyone found out how to edit that?? I need to remove trailing underscore that I have.