# Customizing include-guard for Eclipse CDT

Tags: customization, eclipse-cdt, include-guards

I want an automatically generated include-guard by creating a new C++-class with Eclipse/CDT, but I don't find any way to change the `${include_guard_symbol}` attribute.

My wish is an include-guard with a namespace prefix like following:

```
#ifndef NAMSPACE1_NAMESPACE2_HEADER_HPP
```

But if I use `#ifndef ${namespace_name}_${include_guard_symbol}` for this, it will produce:

```
namepace1::namespace2::_HEADER_HPP
```

How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse-CDT: Use Namespace in automatic generated include-guards](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520943/eclipse-cdt-use-namespace-in-automatic-generated-include-guards)

Answer (score 17):

I had a dig around in the source for CDT, and found an undocumented preference setting you can use to change what is generated by `${include_guard_symbol}`. There's no GUI for it either, but if you add the `codetemplates.includeGuardGenerationScheme` setting to `<projectpath>/.settings/org.eclipse.cdt.ui.prefs`, you can choose between file name (the default), file path or [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier).

Given the file `<projectpath>/src/include/Class.h`, the following values give these results:

- 0 gives an upper-case filename, i.e. `CLASS_H_`
- 1 gives a UUID, for example. `HC9ABE718_D04E_411C_B5A2_F9FE1D9F9409`
- 2 gives an upper-case file path, that is, `SRC_INCLUDE_CLASS_H_`

To avoid any doubt, here's the contents of our `.settings/org.eclipse.cdt.ui.prefs`:

```
codetemplates.includeGuardGenerationScheme=2
eclipse.preferences.version=1
formatter_settings_version=1
```

It's obviously not exactly what you're after, but we use `2` to give us an approximation of our namespaces since, generally speaking, our namespaces follow our folder structure.

The relevant code is in these files in the CDT source:

- `core/org.eclipse.cdt.ui/src/org/eclipse/cdt/ui/PreferenceConstants.java` for the constants for each option
- `core/org.eclipse.cdt.ui/src/org/eclipse/cdt/internal/corext/codemanipulation/StubUtility.java` for the `generateIncludeGuardSymbol()` method that does the work.

It would be really nice to see an extra option added for using the namespace, and a GUI too.

Comment: for my CDT 8.2.0 the prefs file path is:  <EclipseWorkspace>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.cdt.ui.prefs

Comment: In CDT 8.5 (and maybe older) Preferences > C/C++ > Code Style > Name Style then in de Name Categories box choose Code > Include Guard this will show you the three options mentioned in this answer. Still no namespace option though :(

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Eclipse Oxygen (CDT 9.3) and as Eelke described in their comment, there has been a UI setting for this for a while now.

However it only lets you choose from the preset schemes, no namespace or richer customisation options available yet.

Search for 'guard' in the preferences dialog, or navigate to C/C++ > Code Style > Name Style  and select Code > Include Guard and then choose from the available guard schemes.

[image]